# Read Excel sheet with Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I would like to retrieve data from specific cells in a **local** Excel sheet using Javascript and then output it on an HTML page. My function would be something like `readData(row, col)`.

For example:

Cell 1A = "hello"

`<h4><script>readData(1, A)</script></h4>` will show as "hello" on my page.

Every solution I have seen has involved uploading the file first (example below from the `read-excel-file` package), but my Excel file is already a local file within my project.

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('input')
  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(rows) {
      // `rows` is an array of rows
      // each row being an array of cells.
    })
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are referring to this project?

```
https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file
```

I tried using the Node.js example. It works out of the box. The examples for a direct website integration are broken. The project seems still alive, but I would scan the code to decide if to trust the author with your data.

Here how to fix the example (I have no idea for what cases it works!):

Go into the "website" folder. The index.html is a example how to use it. Unfortunately the "read-excel-file.min.js" is missing in the repo. You can download it here (view-source:https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/read-excel-file/read-excel-file.min.js). Put it in the folder and it works.

Maybe someone has a better code for this?

**EDIT (Above answer **not** technically wrong but does not answer the post):**

What you want is not possible to security reasons! Just imagine your javascript (client!) code:

```
inputfile="test.xlsx"
```

I could edit this in my browser to

```
inputfile="super_secret_files_on_server.xlsx"
```

Solution: You could run node.js code on your server and solve it this way, or the user has manually upload a file from his computer. Or use a server side programming languages like php.

Comment: My website is essentially a static website that displays numbers and names listed in an Excel sheet, which is why I want to avoid having the user manually upload the file. Do you have any suggestions for alternative methods of displaying continually updated data (without a database)?

Comment: There are several possible solutions, but all require some form of server side access. Does your server support php? Can data be saved in different formats like csv?

Comment: The data can definitely be saved in different formats. I am planning on deploying my site with DigitalOcean.